# ggplot2 - making a stick plot (plotting a mass spectrum)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot x,y stick plot (like the link in the bottom of the post). I am attempting to make a Mass spectrum plot (basically a stick plot), is there an easy way of doing this with ggplot2? I know how to make the plot with the plot() function in R, however, I would like to be able to make it with ggplot 2, as I need to do some additional modifications afterwards for which I require ggplot2.

So essentially I want to make a x,y stick plot. I am new to R, so bear with me.

[Example of what I want](https://www.google.dk/search?q=mass%20spectrum&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=925&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=nc11VLKBEYLjywO31IDgBQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=VPtYI4tU8NR2WM%253A%3BPlh1sgIYW4YTdM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ausetute.com.au%252Fimages%252Fmspecc5h12.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ausetute.com.au%252Fmassspeco.html%3B311%3B192)

Comment: Thank you, never crossed my mind to search for "needle plot". Tried pretty much everything else. Thank you, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to upload some code and let us know where you are getting stuck. Also, please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) or these [examples](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).

That having been said, I believe this is close to what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1, color = 'white')
```

[image: Example]